# I am getting an error about "is of '.class' expected." and I don't understand why.

Tags: java

The error that i am getting is of '.class' expected. All i want to do is to get the values of the array from the user.
Kindly help me out.

```
int[] array = new int [10];
Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);

// The error comes from the next line.
int array = input.nextInt[];

System.out.println("1. Find Mean");
System.out.println("2. Change Number");
System.out.println("1. Print All");
System.out.println("1. Exit");
```

Comment: rgettman has fixed your syntax error.  But if you really want to get more than one value from your `Scanner`, you'll have to write your own loop.  `Scanner` doesn't have a method that returns a whole array like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a variable named `array`.

```
int[] array = new int [10]; // <-- right there.
int count = 0; // <-- add this.
Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
array[count++] = input.nextInt(); // <-- parens for a method call, 
      // square brackets for the array, and add one to the count.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses `()` for a method call with no parameters, not brackets `[]`.

```
int array = input.nextInt();
```